# Can't SSH access iPad

Tags: ssh, ipad, root

Once some time ago, I had SSH access to my iPad (3rd generation running iOS 5.1.1) and had changed the root password successfully.  Now however, I can no longer access it via SSH.  I have gone back and reset the password numerous times (currently back to the stock password of "alpine") but try as I might, all I ever get is "incorrect password" when trying to `su` from terminal on the device.

Am I missing something about the master.passwd file somehow?  I'm using iFile and also iFunBox, and both applications have no problem reading/changing the contents of the file.

Here is the current file content, does anyone see anything wrong with it?

```
##
# User Database
# 
# This file is the authoritative user database.
##
nobody:*:-2:-2::0:0:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
root:/smx7MYTQIi2M:0:0::0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
mobile:/smx7MYTQIi2M:501:501::0:0:Mobile User:/var/mobile:/bin/sh
daemon:*:1:1::0:0:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
_ftp:*:98:-2::0:0:FTP Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_networkd:*:24:24::0:0:Network Services:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_wireless:*:25:25::0:0:Wireless Services:/var/wireless:/usr/bin/false
_securityd:*:64:64::0:0:securityd:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_mdnsresponder:*:65:65::0:0:mDNSResponder:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_sshd:*:75:75::0:0:sshd Privilege separation:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
_unknown:*:99:99::0:0:Unknown User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

EDIT:  Output of ls -l /etc/passwd is:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 896 Dec 11 13:03 /etc/passwd`

Output for master.passwd is:

`-rw------- 1 root wheel 780 Dec 11 13:03 /etc/master.passwd`

Is there something wrong with these permissions that I'm overlooking?

UPDATE:  Sadly I've gotten no further on this.  I'm at a complete loss as to what to do, other than wipe my iPad and re-jailbreak in case somehow that will help.  Really rather not do that so, I'm still hoping for another solution from someone.

Comment: Do you have a problem with SSH (not being able to connect to the iPad at all) or with su/sudo (not being able to change to user once you are logged in)?

Comment: I cannot connect via SSH at all, from an external device, due to incorrect password.  And if I run terminal on the iPad itself, I can not use su/sudo as it does not recognize the password.

Comment: both root and mobile are using the same stock password alpine (/smx7MYTQIi2M). Can you show permission on the master.password?

Comment: permissions are set to root and wheel.  I've tried changing them both to mobile but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you do `ls -l /etc/passwd` and add the result to the question?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 896 Dec 11 13:03 /etc/passwd

Comment: Sorry, forgot about master.passwd. How are perms there?

Comment: -rw------- 1 root wheel 780 Dec 11 13:03 /etc/master.passwd

Comment: Permissions look ok

Comment: Any other ideas?  I'm completely stumped here.  =(

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new password and pasting it into the master.passwd:

```
 openssl passwd -crypt -salt /s your_new_password
```

you will get somthing like:

```
$ /szArB7q9UBNg
```

replace the text, so it would look like this:

```
root:/szArB7q9UBNg:0:0::0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

After that you may want to try logging in again via SSH with the new password.

Comment: Might be tricky to update master.passwd without root rights

Comment: I've already done that since I can edit the file with iFile on the iPad.  No change, I am still unable to SSH access the iPad for the same reasons.